# Inject two dependecys modules in angular

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I wish to inject two dependences in my module, but angular not accepts this very well , someone can help-me? i´m beginner in angular.

```
  var app = angular.module('aplication', ['infinite-scroll','ngAnimate']);
```

sequence of scripts.
[image]

error:
[image]

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: Your module is called aplication ? have you corrected this spelling?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have loaded the references,

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="infinite-scroll.js"></script>
```

And then,

```
app = angular.module('application', ['ngAnimate', 'infiniteScroll']);
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/m5gvqoGo7MUJSuXWSJKi?p=preview)**

Comment: my sequence is wrong? why i need to put the app.js in the middle of angular-animate and infinite scroll? that is my bug?

Comment: @IgorMonteiro no it is not an issue! where are you loading the app.js?

Comment: no I don´t but I guess that two scripts not working fine together.. tks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130164/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-igor-monteiro).

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my script to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

and works fine!